# What's the difference between opentok SDK's and the opentok REST API?

Tags: opentok, tokbox

Apologies in advance for the seemingly naive question, I'm a hobbyist developer learning the ropes. I noticed the opentok REST API documentation deal mainly with command line stuff, whereas the SDKs (web/node SDKs for example) come packaged with class instances, methods, etc. So is one a reference for the other? How/when does one use the REST API instead of the SDKs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vonage Developer Advocate here.

Our server SDKs provide a language specific wrapper for our REST API. Both are focused on session & token generation and archiving. This logic is usually processed on the server side.

The client SDKs are different in that they provide capabilities for the front-end.